# How to get 2 different key values from a list of dictionaries and append them to another list as sub dictionaries?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, key

Say I have the following list of dictionaries called `sorted_bearish_trading_pairs_info`:

```
sorted_bearish_trading_pairs_info = [{'Trading Pair': 'TCTUSDT', '24h Change': -0.00845, '24h Volume(USDT)': 1926012.715, '0.5d ago Parkinson Volatility': 0.05589759007855682, '0.5d ago True Price Range': -0.03208065994500455, '0.5d ago Maximum Price Range': 0.02016498625114571, 'Last Close Price': 0.01056, 'Last Start Date UTC': Timestamp('2022-07-09 19:00:00')}, {'Trading Pair': 'NMRUSDT', '24h Change': 0.00605, '24h Volume(USDT)': 7340230.2529, '0.5d ago Parkinson Volatility': 0.058917395795956236, '0.5d ago True Price Range': -0.040945790080738224, '0.5d ago Maximum Price Range': 0.03402537485582467, 'Last Close Price': 16.63, 'Last Start Date UTC': Timestamp('2022-07-09 19:00:00')}, {'Trading Pair': 'STEEMUSDT', '24h Change': 0.11779999999999999, '24h Volume(USDT)': 16649505.68257, '0.5d ago Parkinson Volatility': 0.11376745797366504, '0.5d ago True Price Range': -0.05561653860226854, '0.5d ago Maximum Price Range': 0.03732162458836439, 'Last Close Price': 0.2581, 'Last Start Date UTC': Timestamp('2022-07-09 19:00:00')}, {'Trading Pair': 'WINGUSDT', '24h Change': 0.14821, '24h Volume(USDT)': 29672792.925, '0.5d ago Parkinson Volatility': 0.14523057363857397, '0.5d ago True Price Range': -0.05580029368575623, '0.5d ago Maximum Price Range': 0.08076358296622625, 'Last Close Price': 6.43, 'Last Start Date UTC': Timestamp('2022-07-09 19:00:00')}, {'Trading Pair': 'BTCSTUSDT', '24h Change': -0.16942000000000002, '24h Volume(USDT)': 34309469.117, '0.5d ago Parkinson Volatility': 0.15723835541618095, '0.5d ago True Price Range': -0.030425963488843705, '0.5d ago Maximum Price Range': 0.04462474645030439, 'Last Close Price': 9.56, 'Last Start Date UTC': Timestamp('2022-07-09 19:00:00')}]
```

If I execute the following line:

```
[x["0.5d ago Parkinson Volatility"] for x in sorted_bearish_trading_pairs_info]
```

I get the value of each key named `"0.5d ago Parkinson Volatility"` in every dictionary in the list:

```
[0.05589759007855682,
 0.058917395795956236,
 0.11376745797366504,
 0.14523057363857397,
 0.15723835541618095]
```

If I execute the following line:

```
[x["Trading Pair"] for x in sorted_bearish_trading_pairs_info]
```

I get the value of each key named `"Trading Pair"` in every dictionary in the list:

```
['TCTUSDT', 'NMRUSDT', 'STEEMUSDT', 'WINGUSDT', 'BTCSTUSDT']
```

Now, the question I have is how could I get the values of both keys so they end up being presented as the following?

```
[{Trading Pair': 'TCTUSDT',
'0.5d ago Parkinson Volatility': 0.05589759007855682},
{'Trading Pair': 'NMRUSDT',
'0.5d ago Parkinson Volatility': 0.058917395795956236},
{'Trading Pair': 'STEEMUSDT',
'0.5d ago Parkinson Volatility': 0.11376745797366504},
{'Trading Pair': 'WINGUSDT',
'0.5d ago Parkinson Volatility': 0.14523057363857397},
{'Trading Pair': 'BTCSTUSDT',
'0.5d ago Parkinson Volatility': 0.15723835541618095}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
out = [
    {k: d[k] for k in ("Trading Pair", "0.5d ago Parkinson Volatility")}
    for d in sorted_bearish_trading_pairs_info
]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    {
        "Trading Pair": "TCTUSDT",
        "0.5d ago Parkinson Volatility": 0.05589759007855682,
    },
    {
        "Trading Pair": "NMRUSDT",
        "0.5d ago Parkinson Volatility": 0.058917395795956236,
    },
    {
        "Trading Pair": "STEEMUSDT",
        "0.5d ago Parkinson Volatility": 0.11376745797366504,
    },
    {
        "Trading Pair": "WINGUSDT",
        "0.5d ago Parkinson Volatility": 0.14523057363857397,
    },
    {
        "Trading Pair": "BTCSTUSDT",
        "0.5d ago Parkinson Volatility": 0.15723835541618095,
    },
]
```

Comment: Brutal, thank you for the fast solution !